# Program Cannot Find Shared Library While It Is There

Tags: server, 19.10, arm

The title concludes the problem. The system is ubuntu server 19.10 for arm, the program to run is pocketsphinx, a speech recognizer.

Here is the information gathered from the terminal:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/speech_recognition$ pocketsphinx_continuous --help
pocketsphinx_continuous: error while loading shared libraries: libpocketsphinx.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/speech_recognition$ sudo find /usr/local/lib -name libpocketsphinx.so.3
/usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.so.3
```

It seems clearly to me that this lib is in directory `/usr/local/lib`, but the program just cannot find it.

Please help.

Comment: Was `ldconfig` run after the program was installed?

Comment: What does ldd your-program report for where it is looking for that library?  You might have to add to LD_LIBRARY_PATH if no explicit path reported.